# Nested for Loop with Selenium - Fill out Webform

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, webforms

I’m trying to do a nested for loop with selenium to fill out web form. It should be when it goes through each employees xpath, it will input one value in order and skips the other. However, I’m still new and not getting nested for loop clearly, so it’s doing what it’s supposed to do which is sends all the value to each xpath . Is it a break, continue that would help with this? Or Itertools?

What it’s doing when it goes through for loop with each employees xpath:

- Test ID address Contact NAME
- Test ID address Contact NAME
- Test ID address Contact NAME

What I want as it goes through for loop:

- List item
- Test ID Address
- Contact NAME

Appreciate your responses. Thanks!

```
    employees={'//*[@id="ctl00_ctl24_g_dac80454_2d24_4b21_ae61_dd1781b479bd_FormControl0_V1_I1_T1"]',
           '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl24_g_dac80454_2d24_4b21_ae61_dd1781b479bd_FormControl0_V1_I1_T4"]',
           '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl24_g_dac80454_2d24_4b21_ae61_dd1781b479bd_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5"]'}

excel={'test ID',
       'address',
       'Contact NAME'}

for key in employees:
    for value in excel:
        element =driver.find_element_by_xpath(key)
        actions=ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(element)
        actions.click() 
        actions.send_keys(value)
        actions.perform()
```

Comment: Just... switch the loops around? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Since it's a for loop, it's inputting all the items from the excel list in each of the web form fields in the employees list. I would like to put each item in the excel list in the corresponding order in the employees list.

Comment: A bit more details of the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_ will help to understand the _usecase_.

Comment: It's a standard web form that I'm trying to input the text into. Selenium web is supposed to go in the website, find the xpath/html id (which is employees), then input the value that I want (excel) into each of the blanks. I only want corresponding value to go with each other.

-Name: test ID
-City: address
-contact: contact NAME